# How to make a custom UIButton with a unique image and selector for each from an array?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, programmatically-created

I have several UIButtons created from an NSMutableArray. I'm trying to customize each UIButton with a unique image.

On the following line I'm not sure of the syntax to use to set an image for each button from the image array respectively:

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

here's the rest of my code:

```
NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    // Custom UIButton
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 2.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSArray * myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category0.png", @"category-clothing1.png" , @"category2.png", @"category3.png", nil];

    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonArray addObject:btn];

}
```

I would also like a different selector to be called for each button.

Comment: Are you sure to set same action to every button? you can change it also..i guess you must be knowing how to do.

Comment: Are your images added to the target you're building? There is a checkbox in the right bar for them to specify membership. Does it work in the simulator and not a device? If so, check the capitalization, sometimes the simulator is less finicky.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I also need to have a unique action for each unbutton thanks :)

Comment: @Josh the images add fine. the problem is that they are all the same image. I want it to go thru the image array and add image1 for button1, image2 for button2 etc...

Comment: @hanumanDev in that case my answer need vote up and accepteance :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? I just saw your post about needing different actions for each button but I would instead check the sender of the button and adjust the code accordingly inside your (buttonPressed:) method. You should also make sure you have the appropriate amount of images for your button array so a better method may be to only create the amount of buttons based on your image array count. (answer edited to reflect this). I also wanted to add you should get in the habit of also changing the highlighted state of the image when changing the normal state so when you press the image it doesn't go blank.

```
NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray * myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category0.png", @"category-clothing1.png" , @"category2.png", @"category3.png", nil];

for(int i = 0;i < [myImages count]; i++)
{
    // Custom UIButton
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 2.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonArray addObject:btn];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code contains image and selectors from array.
(This code is not compiled-check, may contain some small issue, sorry for inconvenience)

```
NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray * myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category0.png", @"category-clothing1.png" , @"category2.png", @"category3.png", nil];


// You need to assign string name and that should be your method name.
NSMutableArray *selectors=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:@"sel1",@"sel2",@"sel3",@"sel4", nil];


for(int i=0; i<[myImages count]; i++){
    // Custom UIButton
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 2.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    SEL selector = selectorFromString([selectors objectAtIndex:i]);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(selector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [buttonArray addObject:btn];
}
```

Comment: thanks! how would the method then look that's being called? I'm unclear about how the method would know that button3 was touched etc..

Comment: if you have 10 buttons, you are creating 10 images, and similarly you have to create 10 different methods for each button (if they are bit similar then you can to other things). And in the selectors array all selectors(method names are provided), in runtime @selector() will be called with parameter say sel1. Resulting in sel1() method will get called.